# Need help in building a logic in Javascript . Array Logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, logic

Below is the hard coded page of a game Master Mind. The user

I know I need to

1. use Array to store RBGY and some thing to do with indexOf(array
   name) I need to define a right answer (like RRBY hard coded for now)
   I need to check each letter in that Array the user typed and compare
   it with RRBY.

   2. I need show 2 things as answers visually on page so that users know which

      CLOSE :  Right color in the wrong spot 
      EXACT : Right Color in the Right Spot

      For example : 2 close and 1 exact
   3. Also I need the user to play this game only 10 times after that display you lost.
   4. Victory condition is the user gets the right combination RRBY then display Congrats

How do I set all of this up. New to JS.
First Goal is to to make it working and then maybe get complex with display (close and exact).

Can some one help me the structure / function so that I can understand the logic and then I can try and write the syntax (I dont know if this makes sense :)

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
window.onload = init;
 
 function init(){
 var button = document.getElementById("usrButton");
 button.onclick = sayHello;
 }
 
  // my attempt at putting this logic
 var colors = ["R", "B", "Y", "G"];
 var correctAnswer = ["R", "Y", "Y", "G"];
 // maybe i thought I need to define what is the right answer in an array first
 
  
 

 if () {
  // check if all the index in array CorrectAnswer are same as what   user typed. maybe using every method
  // display success message
 }
 
 else
 // just display what the user types in on the page with display logic 
 
 else if {
 // if the user leaves the text box blank . Alert him to enter some values
 }
 

 function sayHello(){
 var usrTxt = document.getElementById("usrTxt");
 var usrName = usrTxt.value;
 var display = document.getElementById("displayHere");
 
 var currentOutput = display.innerHTML;  
 
 display.innerHTML = currentOutput + usrName '<br>'; 

 var div = document.getElementById("total");
 div.appendChild(p);
 
 //display.innerHTML = usrName;
 
 //var p = document.createElement("p");
 //p.innerHTML = "looks good";
 

 }
```

```css
body { color: black; background-color: #d0e4fe; margin-left: 45px; padding: 0;}
 h1 { color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;}
 p { font-family: arial, verdana; font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1> Master Mind</h1>
<p> <b>Game Rules</b>
<ul>
<li>The user gets 10 chances to enter their guess of 4 colors from RGBY. After which you lose</li>
<li>Right Answer is  - Correct Color in the Right Spot </li>
<li>Close Answer is  - Correct Color but in the wrong Spot</li>

<li></li>
</ul>

Enter your name and click Submit.</p>
<input type="text" id="usrTxt">
<input type="button" onclick="" id="usrButton" value="Submit">
<div id="total">
<p id="displayHere"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

==================================================

```js
 window.onload = init;
 
 function init(){
 var button = document.getElementById("usrButton");
 button.onclick = submitAnswer;
 }

// global counter variable 
//var i = 0;
 
 function submitAnswer(){
  var usrTxt;
  var answers = []; 
   //define a new variable and make a empty array
  
  answers.push(document.getElementById('usrTxt').value);
   // push the content the user types as array in a variable called answers

  //defined a new variable so that I can display what the user entered as it is 
  var display = document.getElementById("displayHere");
  display.innerHTML = usrTxt; 
  
  }
```

```css
 body { color: black; background-color: #d0e4fe; margin-left: 45px; padding: 0;}
 h1 { color: black; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;}
 p { font-family: arial, verdana; font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1> Master Mind</h1>
<p> <b>Game Rules</b>
<ul>
<li>The user gets 10 chances to enter their guess of 4 colors from RGBY. After which you lose</li>
<li>Right Answer is  - Correct Color in the Right Spot </li>
<li>Close Answer is  - Correct Color but in the wrong Spot</li>

<li></li>
</ul>

Enter your Guess and click Submit.</p>
<input type="text" id="usrTxt">
<input type="button" onclick="submitAnswer()" id="usrButton" value="Submit">
<div id="total">
<p id="displayHere"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like homework to me. What have you really tried, I don't see any logic implemented really. But if you need help, here's a start. Answering your 4 questions. **1.** Write a function that takes the input string from user and set into a array. **2.** Write two checks, 1 for index check of 0, 1, 2, 3 for the 4 colors. If any of them match, notify user of correct color on which index. Check array again for contains() of color and notify again. **3.** Iterate over an integer, set to 0, each submit adds 1 to the count. at 9 return you lose. **4.** User array matches set answer, return you win.

Comment: Tyler thanks I sure need help. These 4 answers help. I will try and attempt these.

Comment: Tyler I have attempted to write the first function but my browser returns undefined and there are no errors in log. What am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
answer='RYYG'
function haveAguess(){
    guess=textBox.value
    guessDiv.innerText=guess
    if(!guess){
        alert('No Guess Entered!')
        return
    }
        else if(guess==answer){
            alert('Congratulations')
            return
        }
            else{
                result=[]
                x='Wrong'
                y='Wrong'
                for(i in guess){
                    if(guess[i]==answer[i]){
                        x='Correct';    y='Right'
                    }
                        else if(answer.indexOf(guess[i])>=0)    x='Correct';
                    result.push('Color ['+i+'] is the: '+x+' Color in the '+y+' Spot');
                }
                displayDiv.innerText=result.join('\n')
            }
}
```

I think it meets all your needs...

### **EDITED**

This is how it works...

1. `guess=textBox.value`; retrieves the users guess from the text box.
2. `guessDiv.innerText=guess`; displays the guess on screen.
3. `if(!guess)`; `!guess` is the same as `guess==''`, or no guess entered, so alert the user and return/end the function.
4. `else if(guess==answer)`; if the guess is the same as the `answer` variable, the congratulate the user and end the function.
5. `else`; if the user entered some text ie: `guess!=''` and the guess does **not** match the answer ie: `guess!=answer`, then:
   5.1. `result=[]`; ready an array to return the results.
   5.2. `x='Wrong'; y='Wrong'`; set x & y defaults to 'Wrong'.
   5.3. `for(i in guess)`; loop through every character in the `guess` string.
   5.3.1. `if(guess[i]==answer[i])`; if the character at `[i]` in `guess` matches the character at `[i]` in `answer` ie:`guess[i]=='R' && answer[i]=='R'`, then the result is 'Correct color in Right place' so change `x` & `y` to match.
   5.3.2. `else if(answer.indexOf(guess[i])>=0)`; if the character at `[i]` in `guess` does **not** match the character at `[i]` in `answer` ie:`guess[i]=='Y' && answer[i]=='R'`, then `answer.indexOf()` checks `answer` to see if it contains the value `guess[i]`, if `false` it returns `-1`, if `true` it returns the index of `guess[i]`. `>=0` if the returned value (-1 or *index*) is greater than or equal to 0 then `guess[i]` is present in `answer` so change `x` as the result is 'Correct color in Wrong place'.
   5.3.3. `result.push(...)`; now `x` & `y` are modified to display correctly, append the display string to the end of the `results` array using `.push()`.
   5.4. `displayDiv.innerText`; now the loop has finished, `results` contains a string for ever character in the users guess and you just need to display it in your *display div*.
   5.4.1. `result.join('\n')`; joins the `results` array together with **'\n'**, before it displays as `innerText`...

Need more help?!  Try these:
http://www.w3schools.com/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to run this it throws error in chrome "Uncaught ReferenceError: textBox is not defined". I added a document.addEventListener to check if the text box is getting recognized. I could see that textbox is showing my values.

Comment: this is first time for me. so bear with me. I understood till guess is blank and check for right answer after that I am lost.

Comment: Sorry `textBox` & `displayDiv` are my own names for the elements you are using, `textBox.value` is shorthand for `document.getElementById('textBox').value` and the same goes for `displayDiv`, just swap `.value` for `.innerText`... apologies for the rash explanation it was getting late! I've tried to explain it a bit better above ^^^. **PS** as a *newbie* I would most certainly recommend `w3schools.com` that's where I began and I still use them till this day!

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation !!. I am going through it and sorry to keep you late :)                                                                                                      I am on the w3 schools website everyday since 2 weeks :) I will refer mozilla also. Currently I am practicing from Head first with HTML and Javascript.

Comment: explain what you mean by 'practicing from Head first...'

Comment: So in the book there are some examples or projects for each topic and that is what I am trying to do. For ex. How to add to dom > Append Child etc

Comment: sorry dude you'd have to tell me the name of the book? it's irrelevant now anyway, I was just checking weather **head** meant **<head>** or not and it doesn't! **PS** instead of using `window.onload = init;` try looking at **jQuery** and it's `$(document).ready()` ie: at the end of the `<script>` tag in the `<head>` tag write `$(document).ready(function(){init()})`. Its like a storage compartment for anything to be done when the *document* loads, rather than messing with `window.onload`.  **jQuery** is a handy thing to know and I wish I learnt it when I learnt **JavaScript**!

Comment: I am so sorry. about the name of the book. My apologies. The name of the book is "head First HTML 5 programming" by Freeman and Robson

Comment: I was not able to understand how to go about doing these                                                                             1) How do I add counter to this code so that the user can play it only 10 times. After that it will alert you lost and reload to play new game.                                                                                                       2) How do I display Just exactly what the user typed in the textbox and each time it should come in a new line                      For e.g. (RYGG - 2 Close and 2 Exact)

Comment: please do me a favor, put this code `console.log('Result is:',[document.documentMode,document.compatMode])` into any webpage you are running, open the console in your browser and tell me what the result of this code is? it will look something like `Result is: [undefined, "CSS1Compat"]`

Comment: if your understanding is that i'm looking for you browser name and compatibility mode the **yes**... there should be an arrow to expand `Array[2]` and see it's content, i'm interested in the value of the second item `Array[1]`... the code i gave you was kind'a made up on the spot, i never tested it coz i know it's sound, but i'm gona have to write my own version of this game to really aid you so do bare with me if you're interested. besides the extra two things you asked for is there anything else you want it to do?

Comment: I got this :  Result is: [undefined, "BackCompat"]

Comment: Perfect. Cheers! please wait while i work on this, but that doesn't mean don't ask anyone else in the meantime, this place is full of coders far more advanced than me!

Comment: I got this :  0: undefined1: "BackCompat"length: 2__proto__: Array[0]  When I clicked on the arrow

Comment: I will wait for you ...as I want to understand more on this array and how to set the logic. (designer in me does not want to be logical)

Comment: I hope this helps for the extra 2nd point. I was going for something like this on the screen as result

RGBY - 1 Exact  3 Close
RGBB - 2 Exact  2 Close
RGGB - 2 Exact  2 Close

So 2 Exact are RG (red and green) and the user can guess by seeing.  After this he gets to play 7 times and now user has to guess only the last 2 places.

Comment: I get the **Exact**/**Close** idea that's no problem, but what is the difference between being 'Close' and 'Wrong', or are they the same thing?

Comment: You are right technically yes they both can be the same.                         But my guess is since only all these 4 colors (RGBY) are required for the user to enter and if I put (IOPL) that could be considered wrong.

Comment: but if i add this: `textBox.onchange=function(){v=this.value;spl=v.split('');for(i in spl){dex=answer.indexOf(spl[i]);if(dex<0){spl.splice(dex,1)}};this.value=spl.join('');}`. Then you can **not** type **IOPL** into the textbox only the letters **RGBY** will show up when typed!?

Comment: Yes thats cool. The user should ONLY be able to enter a combination of RGBY (RRGB or RYYG etc etc)

Comment: I am sorry if I lost you on the IOPL

Comment: **IOPL** are just letters you enter. try that code on any text box and you can't type any other letters than **RGBY**. **PS** if you do use it change `textBox` to your text box id, and edit this part `spl.splice(dex,1)` to `spl.splice(i,1)` or it won't work, so i just found out! bed time dude will pick this up 2moro...